# How to remove a book from a Books collection

Tags: books

In Books app we can organize books in collections. We can have multiple collections and a book can even be in multiple collections.

But how can I remove a book from a collection? I don't mean to delete the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my iPad I select the collection, then find the book and then click the three dots at the right of the book icon.

I then take the bin icon and that asks me to confirm I want to remove it from the collectIon I am in.

It does not delete it from the library or other collections at this point.

Not the greatest idea to use the same icon as the delete function! :-O